# ソース元IPでアクセス制限（iptables や access list 等）を行う方法について

Tags: network, iptables

下図のような構成になっている場合、ルータ側でこのようなことは制御を行うことは可能でしょうか？
（図示のとおり、各セグメントのデフォルトゲートウェイは末尾254です。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■やりたい事
source: 172.16.1.100のクライアントから
dst: 192.168.1.20へのアクセスだけを許したい
（同セグメントに存在している192.168.1.200へのアクセスは禁止）

ルータになりうるのはCisco機器 or VyOSなので
アクセスリストかiptablesどちらかでの対応となります。
（Cisco機器ではできました）

調べたところソース元IPで制限をかける場合はPBR(ポリシーベースルーティング)?を利用しないとできなさそうなのですが、iptablesでそれを行うことは可能でしょうか？

お詳しい方いらっしゃいましたら経路の制御を行う書き方
（iptablesでの制御 or VyOSでの書き方）を教えて頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 「192.168.2.10側のサーバーでiptablesをかけるのではなく、あくまでもサーバー側で制御したい」の後で出てくる"サーバー"は何を指していますか？　普通、サーバ -- ルータ -- クライアントという構成だと思うのですがクライアントは存在しないのですか？

Comment: Fumu様ご回答ありがとうございます。わかりづらい説明となってしまい誠に申し訳ございませんでいた。ここでいっている”サーバー”はルーターのことです。（ルーターはCiscoのL3またはLinuxベースのVyOSというサーバーどちらかを利用したいと考えています）

Comment: 少し質問が分かりにくい気がしました。Ciscoのアクセスリストの書き方と、Linux iptablesの書き方を知りたいということですか？PBRを使わないといけないというのはどういう理由でしょうか。Linuxはcentosと書かれてますがコメントにはVyOSと書かれてますので一度質問を整理してみて「編集」してみることをオススメします。質問を編集するのはSOで積極的に推奨されていますので コメント欄に追加情報を書くのではなく 質問を書きなおしてみてください。そうすれば回答が付きやすくなると思いますよ。

Comment: take88様ご回答ありがとうございます。ごちゃごちゃとなってしまいましたので、編集しなおしてみます。アドバイスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ネットマスクの記載がありませんが、/24 と想定しています。
ルーティングは設定済みで、192.168.3.0/24 <--> 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.2.0/24 間はルータを経由して通信できるものとします。

iptables の FORWARD チェインで接続元IPアドレス、接続先IPアドレスのペアで許可／拒否すればいいと思います。

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.3.200 -d 192.168.1.10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.3.200 -d 192.168.2.10 -j DROP
```

こういう単純なことではなく、もっと複雑なことをやろうとしているのでしょうか？
図では 192.168.1.10 と 192.168.2.10 が同じネットワークセグメントのように見えますし。

Comment: taichi yanagiya様ご回答ありがとうございます！
問題文を編集しなおしてしまいましたが、おっしゃるとおりのことをやりたかったのです、ありがとうございます。